# Installed Ubuntu, partitions not visible

Tags: 15.10, partitioning

Today I installed Ubuntu 15.10 from USB. I formatted entire 1000GB HDD and created 2 partitions, one of 750GB, and the other of 250GB.
The problem is, I can't find them anywhere.

Typed `lsblk` in terminal and got this:

```
dario@PUNISHER-PC:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 698,5G  0 part /home
└─sda2   8:2    0   233G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So partitions are there but I can't access them as on Windows. Is that normal or what? I don't have them listed here even:

[image: screenshot]

Would expect them to be there.
Even GParted is showing them, don't know what is the problem.

Help?

Comment: It's normal. Windows doesn't by default support ext4 and other filesystems. Only FAT12, FAT16, FAT32 and NTFS.

Comment: So how can I put files on my second partition?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but you can install Ext2Fs on Windows and you will be able to access Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot look completely normal. Under Linux default mountpoints (/home, /boot, /root etc.) aren't shown like on Windows.

All files that you write in your home directory (downloads, documents, videos..)  go to sda1.

sda2 is root partition in your case, so to put files there just copy them in /root directory. But it's not recommended to use /root partition for regular files, it's mostly for system only.

Comment: Thanks!
But is there a way to make shortcuts for partitions? I really miss that option

Answer (score -1):

You are looking at your user's home directory /home/your-username-here/

Try Računalo (computer) instead on the left hand side. That will list / and /home.

Comment: what do you mean by left hand side?

Comment: The menu/list on the left in your screenshot, it says "Računalo"

Comment: Partitions ain't there :/